# Get imageviews current scale value

Tags: android, eclipse, imageview, scale

```
    Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5);
    anim.setFillAfter(true); // Needed to keep the result of the animation
    anim.setDuration((long) durationPlayer);
    imageView1.startAnimation(anim);
```

This is what I have to scale an ImageView, what I want to do if possible to get the scale value on a button click so between 0.0f and 1.0f. Essentially I need to get the ImageView width and height values however checking for those directly only returns the width and height at a scale factor of 1. I've googled but can't find anything, does that mean it's at all possible? Any other ideas would be helpful.

In short is it possible to get the size of an imageview whilst it is in a scale animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't ask the ImageView for it's height and width in the middle of an animation, because the animation does not progressively change the size of the view as it runs the animation. It only changes how the view draws itself.

One easy option is to keep track of the time stamp when you start the animation, and then measure the interval until the user clicks the button. Then calculate how far through the animations duration the interval is, and multiply that by the image's width and height. Like this:

```
long startTime;
...
imageView1.startAnimation(anim);
startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.my_button) {
        long millisElapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        double percentage = Math.max(0d, Math.min(1d, millisElapsed / (double) durationPlayer));
        int width = (int) (imageView1.getWidth() * percentage);
        int height = (int) (imageView1.getHeight() * percentage);
    }
}
```